# Stored Procedure With sp_executesql Giving Error And Make No Sense

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Students].[spExamsSchedulesRead]
    @ActionCode             nVarchar(10),
    @UserID                 BigInt,     
    @SearchText             nVarchar(MAX),
    @ExamScheduleID         nVarchar(50),
    @ExamTypeID             nVarchar(50),
    @ClassSectionID         nVarchar(50),
    @SessionID              nVarchar(50),   
    @SortExp                NVARCHAR(100),
    @SortDir                nVarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Err_Message nVarChar(Max)
    DECLARE @FullSelect Nvarchar(MAX)   
    DECLARE @WhereClause Nvarchar(MAX)  

    DECLARE @tTable TABLE
        (   
           ExamScheduleID [bigint] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,                        
           ExamTypeID           [bigint],
           ClassSectionID       [bigint],
           ClassID              [bigint],
           SectionID            [bigint],
           SessionID            [bigint],         
           ExamTypeEN           [nVarchar](100),
           ExamType             [nVarchar](100),
           SessionEN            [nVarchar](100),
           [Session]            [nVarchar](100),
           SessionActive        [Bit],         
           ClassNameEN          [nVarchar](100),
           ClassName            [nVarchar](100),
           SectionNameEN        [nVarchar](100),
           SectionName          [nVarchar](100),
           ClassSectionActive   [Bit],
           DateFrom             [DateTime],
           DateTo               [DateTime],
           InstructionsEN       [nVarchar](max),
           Instructions         [nVarchar](max),
           Remarks              [nVarchar](max),
           Active               [bit],
           AddedBy              [bigint],
           AddedByUsername      [nVarchar](150),
           DateAdded            [datetime],
           LastModifiedBy       [bigint],
           LastModifiedByUsername [nVarchar](150),
           DateModified         [datetime]          
          )

    ---------------------------------------------------------
    SET @FullSelect =  'SELECT  * FROM [Students].[vExamsSchedules] '       
    SET @WhereClause =  ' WHERE ExamScheduleID <> 0 '
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    IF (ISNULL(@ExamScheduleID,0) <> 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @WhereClause= @WhereClause +' AND (ExamScheduleID = ' + @ExamScheduleID + ') '
        END

    IF (ISNULL(@ExamTypeID,'') <> '')
        BEGIN
            SET @WhereClause= @WhereClause +' AND (ExamTypeID IN (' + @ExamTypeID + ')) '
        END

    IF (ISNULL(@ClassSectionID,'') <> '')
        BEGIN
            SET @WhereClause= @WhereClause +' AND (ClassSectionID IN (' + @ClassSectionID + ')) '
        END

    IF (ISNULL(@SessionID,'') <> '')
        BEGIN
            SET @WhereClause= @WhereClause +' AND (SessionID IN (' + @SessionID + ')) '
        END 

    IF ISNULL(@SearchText, '') <> ''
        BEGIN
            SET @SearchText = '%' + @SearchText + '%'
            SET @WhereClause= @WhereClause + ' AND (ISNULL(ExamTypeEN,'''') + ISNULL(ExamType,'''') + ISNULL(SessionEN,'''') + 
                              ISNULL([Session],'''') + ISNULL(ClassNameEN,'''') + ISNULL(ClassName,'''') + 
                              ISNULL(SectionNameEN,'''') + ISNULL(SectionName,'''') + ISNULL(InstructionsEN,'''') + 
                              ISNULL(Instructions,'''') + ISNULL(Remarks,'''') + ISNULL(AddedByUsername,'''') + 
                              ISNULL(LastModifiedByUsername,'''') LIKE ''' + @SearchText + ''')'

        END

    SET @FullSelect =@FullSelect + @WhereClause 
    INSERT INTO @tTable
    EXEC sp_executesql @FullSelect
    --PRINT @FullSelect     

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            IF @ActionCode ='1' --Read Data to display in ListView
                BEGIN               
                    SELECT * FROM @tTable ORDER BY 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamTypeEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ExamTypeEN END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamTypeEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN ExamTypeEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamType' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ExamType END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamType' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN ExamType END DESC,                   
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SessionEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN SessionEN END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SessionEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN SessionEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'Session' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN [Session] END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'Session' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN [Session] END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ClassNameEN END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN ClassNameEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassName' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ClassName END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassName' AND @SortDir = 'DESC'  THEN ClassName END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN SectionNameEN END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN SectionNameEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionName' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN SectionName END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionName' AND @SortDir = 'DESC'    THEN SectionName END DESC                   
                END

            ELSE IF @ActionCode ='1.1' --Read Data to display in ListView
                BEGIN               
                    SELECT * FROM @tTable WHERE SessionActive='True' AND ClassSectionActive='True' AND Active='True' ORDER BY
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamTypeEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ExamTypeEN END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamTypeEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN ExamTypeEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamType' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ExamType END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamType' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN ExamType END DESC,                   
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SessionEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN SessionEN END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SessionEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN SessionEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'Session' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN [Session] END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'Session' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN [Session] END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ClassNameEN END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN ClassNameEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassName' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ClassName END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassName' AND @SortDir = 'DESC'  THEN ClassName END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN SectionNameEN END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN SectionNameEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionName' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN SectionName END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionName' AND @SortDir = 'DESC'    THEN SectionName END DESC                                   
                END

            ELSE IF @ActionCode ='2'
                BEGIN
                    SELECT * FROM @tTable WHERE ExamScheduleID=@ExamScheduleID
                END 


        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        RETURN @@ROWCOUNT

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO [Security].ErrorLogs(ErrorDate, ErrorBy, ErrorNo, ErrorLine, ErrorState,
                    ErrorSeverity, ErrorProcedure, ErrorMessage) VALUES
                    ([Security].fnUTCDateTime(@UserID),@UserID, 
                     CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS nVarchar(20)),
                     CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS nVarchar(20)),
                     CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS nVarchar(20)),
                     CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS nVarchar(20)),
                     CAST(ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS nVarchar(150)),
                     CAST(ERROR_MESSAGE() AS nVarchar(max)))
        RAISERROR (@Err_Message,11, 1)
        RETURN -1
    END CATCH
END
```

Now when I execute this stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [Students].[spExamsSchedulesRead]
     @ActionCode = N'1',
     @UserID = 1,
     @SearchText = NULL,
     @ExamScheduleID = NULL,
     @ExamTypeID = NULL,
     @ClassSectionID = NULL,
     @SessionID = NULL,
     @SortExp = NULL,
     @SortDir = NULL

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

it returns the following error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

When I debug the stored procedure, it gets to the line where

```
EXEC sp_executesql @FullSelect
```

is then it went out of debugging... and show the SQL query....which is actually corrent.... because when I copy and run that SQL query separately that is running...

Please anybody can help why this error is popping up? Although I have delete the view and stored procedure, created them again with same name and even  with different names, I get get that same error. Not to forget I have same kind of stored procedures for my all other tables, and those are running just fine. Only this one is causing an error.

Comment: `SELECT *` and not having an insert list on an insert statement is a bad idea. The first thing you need to do is change your `SELECT *` to actually contain a column list. Then add a column list to your insert. Then observe the columns that are being inserted into datetime columns. Remove them one by one until you find the one that is causing the error. The select is proabbly fine. It's trying to insert an invalid piece of data into a datetime that is the problem.

Comment: You have a number of challenges in this procedure. First is that is vulnerable to sql injection. Additionally you have a couple of things going on here. This is a type of catch all query which can cause significant performance issues if not handled correctly. Here is an article explaining how to deal with this type of query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are getting an error and the insert in the catch block is giving the error: "Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime"
The error seems to be coming because your ActionCode is 1 and nothing gets appended to the OrderBy clause.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? I made sure the @FullSelect rows statement matched the Table Variable order. It parses, but I don't have the data..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Students].[spExamsSchedulesRead]
    @ActionCode             nVarchar(10),
    @UserID                 BigInt,     
    @SearchText             nVarchar(MAX),
    @ExamScheduleID         nVarchar(50),
    @ExamTypeID             nVarchar(50),
    @ClassSectionID         nVarchar(50),
    @SessionID              nVarchar(50),   
    @SortExp                NVARCHAR(100),
    @SortDir                nVarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Err_Message nVarChar(Max)
    DECLARE @FullSelect Nvarchar(MAX)   
    DECLARE @WhereClause Nvarchar(MAX)  

    DECLARE @tTable TABLE
        (   
           ExamScheduleID [bigint] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,                        
           ExamTypeID           [bigint],
           ClassSectionID       [bigint],
           ClassID              [bigint],
           SectionID            [bigint],
           SessionID            [bigint],         
           ExamTypeEN           [nVarchar](100),
           ExamType             [nVarchar](100),
           SessionEN            [nVarchar](100),
           [Session]            [nVarchar](100),
           SessionActive        [Bit],         
           ClassNameEN          [nVarchar](100),
           ClassName            [nVarchar](100),
           SectionNameEN        [nVarchar](100),
           SectionName          [nVarchar](100),
           ClassSectionActive   [Bit],
           DateFrom             [DateTime],
           DateTo               [DateTime],
           InstructionsEN       [nVarchar](max),
           Instructions         [nVarchar](max),
           Remarks              [nVarchar](max),
           Active               [bit],
           AddedBy              [bigint],
           AddedByUsername      [nVarchar](150),
           DateAdded            [datetime],
           LastModifiedBy       [bigint],
           LastModifiedByUsername [nVarchar](150),
           DateModified         [datetime]          
          )

    ---------------------------------------------------------
    SET @FullSelect =  'SELECT  ExamScheduleID,
                                ExamTypeID,
                                ClassSectionID,
                                ClassID,
                                SectionID,
                                SessionID,
                                ExamTypeEN,
                                ExamType,
                                SessionEN,
                                [Session],
                                SessionActive,
                                ClassNameEN,
                                ClassName,
                                SectionNameEN,
                                SectionName,
                                ClassSectionActive,
                                DateFrom,
                                DateTo,
                                InstructionsEN,
                                Instructions,
                                Remarks,
                                Active,
                                AddedBy,
                                AddedByUsername,
                                DateAdded,
                                LastModifiedBy,
                                LastModifiedByUsername,
                                DateModified FROM [Students].[vExamsSchedules] '       
    SET @WhereClause =  ' WHERE ExamScheduleID <> 0 '
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    IF (ISNULL(@ExamScheduleID,0) <> 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @WhereClause= @WhereClause +' AND (ExamScheduleID = ' + @ExamScheduleID + ') '
        END

    IF (ISNULL(@ExamTypeID,'') <> '')
        BEGIN
            SET @WhereClause= @WhereClause +' AND (ExamTypeID IN (' + @ExamTypeID + ')) '
        END

    IF (ISNULL(@ClassSectionID,'') <> '')
        BEGIN
            SET @WhereClause= @WhereClause +' AND (ClassSectionID IN (' + @ClassSectionID + ')) '
        END

    IF (ISNULL(@SessionID,'') <> '')
        BEGIN
            SET @WhereClause= @WhereClause +' AND (SessionID IN (' + @SessionID + ')) '
        END 

    IF ISNULL(@SearchText, '') <> ''
        BEGIN
            SET @SearchText = '%' + @SearchText + '%'
            SET @WhereClause= @WhereClause + ' AND (ISNULL(ExamTypeEN,'''') + ISNULL(ExamType,'''') + ISNULL(SessionEN,'''') + 
                              ISNULL([Session],'''') + ISNULL(ClassNameEN,'''') + ISNULL(ClassName,'''') + 
                              ISNULL(SectionNameEN,'''') + ISNULL(SectionName,'''') + ISNULL(InstructionsEN,'''') + 
                              ISNULL(Instructions,'''') + ISNULL(Remarks,'''') + ISNULL(AddedByUsername,'''') + 
                              ISNULL(LastModifiedByUsername,'''') LIKE ''' + @SearchText + ''')'

        END

    SET @FullSelect =@FullSelect + @WhereClause 
    INSERT INTO @tTable
    EXEC sp_executesql @FullSelect
    --PRINT @FullSelect     

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            IF @ActionCode ='1' --Read Data to display in ListView
                BEGIN               
                    SELECT * FROM @tTable ORDER BY 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamTypeEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ExamTypeEN END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamTypeEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN ExamTypeEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamType' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ExamType END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamType' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN ExamType END DESC,                   
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SessionEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN SessionEN END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SessionEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN SessionEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'Session' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN [Session] END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'Session' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN [Session] END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ClassNameEN END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN ClassNameEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassName' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ClassName END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassName' AND @SortDir = 'DESC'  THEN ClassName END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN SectionNameEN END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN SectionNameEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionName' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN SectionName END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionName' AND @SortDir = 'DESC'    THEN SectionName END DESC                   
                END

            ELSE IF @ActionCode ='1.1' --Read Data to display in ListView
                BEGIN               
                    SELECT * FROM @tTable WHERE SessionActive='True' AND ClassSectionActive='True' AND Active='True' ORDER BY
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamTypeEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ExamTypeEN END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamTypeEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN ExamTypeEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamType' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ExamType END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ExamType' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN ExamType END DESC,                   
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SessionEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN SessionEN END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SessionEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN SessionEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'Session' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN [Session] END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'Session' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN [Session] END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ClassNameEN END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN ClassNameEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassName' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN ClassName END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'ClassName' AND @SortDir = 'DESC'  THEN ClassName END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN SectionNameEN END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionNameEN' AND @SortDir = 'DESC' THEN SectionNameEN END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionName' AND @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN SectionName END ASC, 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExp = 'SectionName' AND @SortDir = 'DESC'    THEN SectionName END DESC                                   
                END

            ELSE IF @ActionCode ='2'
                BEGIN
                    SELECT * FROM @tTable WHERE ExamScheduleID=@ExamScheduleID
                END 


        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        RETURN @@ROWCOUNT

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO [Security].ErrorLogs(ErrorDate, ErrorBy, ErrorNo, ErrorLine, ErrorState,
                    ErrorSeverity, ErrorProcedure, ErrorMessage) VALUES
                    ([Security].fnUTCDateTime(@UserID),@UserID, 
                     CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS nVarchar(20)),
                     CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS nVarchar(20)),
                     CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS nVarchar(20)),
                     CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS nVarchar(20)),
                     CAST(ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS nVarchar(150)),
                     CAST(ERROR_MESSAGE() AS nVarchar(max)))
        RAISERROR (@Err_Message,11, 1)
        RETURN -1
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for answering............finally after many hours headache....i got the problem....Specially thanks to Nick.McDermaid.........I removed all columns and start adding column one by one....and guess what....In View my last Columns were in this squence.

```html
AddedBy    [bigint],
AddedByUsername      [nVarchar](150),
DateAdded            [datetime],
```

and i was adding them in this squence.

```html
AddedBy    [bigint],
DateAdded            [datetime],
AddedByUsername      [nVarchar](150),
```